# How can i make a string of an image in my project resources?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I added an image to my project.
On the solution i did on my project name: Mouse right click button > Properties > Resources > Add Existing File

And in my code i have this line:

```
backTexture = TextureLoader.FromFile(D3Ddev, Properties.Resources.test);
scannerTexture = TextureLoader.FromFile(D3Ddev, @"D:\Buttons\test\test1.png");
```

The second line is ok the first one i tried to use the Resources but i'm getting error since the backTexture should get the second parameter as string and not image.

What can i do ?

Comment: Why are you handling the two files (they are both files, aren't they) differently? If you say the second one works, then do the same for the first one, reference it directly as a file.

Comment: How do i reference it directly as file so it will be on the project all the time and if someone else will run the program he will not need the file/s on his hard drive ?

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: Error 2 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to 'string' and the first error is also on same line: Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.TextureLoader.FromFile(Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.Device, string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: You probably want to make the texture file an "embedded resource". And then read it using TextureLoader.FromStream() instead of TextureLoader.FromFile(). Try Googling how to make an embedded resource and read it with a stream reader.

Comment: From that error message it sounds like you have succeeded in making the texture file into an embedded resource, but of Bitmap type instead of byte stream. I'm not familiar with TextureLoader, but I don't think it can accept a .Net Bitmap object as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with TextureLoader, but you have to write the resource to a file first before you can use (except if TextureLoader can load straight from a stream).

string file = @"C:\Yourfile.ext";
File.WriteAllBytes(file, Properties.Resources.test);
TextureLoader.FromFile(D3Ddev, file);

You can also use File.WriteAllText if the file in the resources is a text file.